# When I use system("command") in c++, could I call the cygwin instead of normal command line?

Tags: c++

Normally, I use `system("command line")` in a c++ application, I will execute this command in command prompt. Is there anyway or any other code, that I could execute my command directly in Cygwin?

Comment: Is the calling application running on Cygwin?

Comment: you can try to set the `COMSPEC` environment variable, but I would rather explicitly invoke the cygwin shell. explicit = good, implicit = bad. or at least pretty fragile.

Comment: @Brian, for example, I program Application A, but I want to use B.exe as well. So I use `system("B.exe --config ...")` in my program. But somehow the B.exe could not run well in command line, but run successfully in cygwin. So I think is there some way I could not use the command prompt but cygwin directly.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, should I use `SetEnvironmentVariable("COMSPEC", "C:\\cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe")`? I could not understand how to invoke the cygwin shell.

Comment: @cindywmiao Is it possible that `B.exe` wasn't found? Or do you mean it ran, but was buggy?

Comment: @Brian No, I already try in commandline, it gives very weird error like could not open SPHERE(a lib I use). And I try to add the lib into my environment path, it does not work neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `system()` function uses `cmd` in Windows. However, it is possible to instantiate Cygwin from the command line and run a command, like so:

```
system("C:/cygwin/bin/bash -c \"echo hi\"");
```

This will cause the command `echo hi` to be run by Cygwin bash, and the output to be printed in your program's standard out.

Be sure to replace `C:/cygwin/bin/bash` with the appropriate location, if you installed Cygwin elsewhere.

Comment: I test it, but it would not work for me.